# unique sound when hovering multiple instance div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, hover

i'm trying to play a unique sound as i hover one div element with a certain class (**.trigger**).
my problem is, that i have multiple instances of this div class, which means no matter which of the divs i hover, the (same) sound is played.

my *dreamscenario* would be, that as soon as the next div is hovered (and hopefully the next sound is played), any previous sound stops (i am using soundfiles that are 1-2 seconds long).

i have included my audio via html5 within the div i am trying to use as a trigger.

```
<div class="trigger">
    <audio id="sound" preload="auto">
        <source src="sound1.mp3"></source>
        <source src="sound1.mp3"></source>
    </audio>
</div>

<div class="trigger">
    <audio id="sound" preload="auto">
         <source src="sound2.mp3"></source>
         <source src="sound2.mp3"></source>
    </audio>
</div>
```

and i'm using this script:

```
$(".trigger")
  $(this).each(function(i) {
    if (i != 0) { 
      $("#sound")
        .clone()
        .attr("id", "sound" + i)
        .appendTo($(this).parent()); 
    }
    $(this).data("cnt", i);
  })
  $(this).mouseenter(function() {
    $("#sound" + $(this).data("cnt"))[0].play();
  });
$("#sound").attr("id", "sound0");
```

i'd be gracious for any help and better idea to achieve this :)
i'm a terrible novice — sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Simple as that?

```
$('.trigger').hover(
    function() {
        sound = $(this).children()[0];
        sound.play();
    }, function() {
        sound.pause();
        sound.currentTime = 0;
    }
);
```

**Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/VwSLj/5/

Comment: excellent! thanks alot — that's working.
but is there any possiblity to play the sound to the end or until another sound is hovered instead of stopping it when the mouse leaves the div?

Answer (score 0):

First change from ID to class as ID selector is not supposed to be duplicated.

```
<div class="trigger">
    <audio class="sound" preload="auto">
        <source src="sound1.mp3"></source>
        <source src="sound1.mp3"></source>
    </audio>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(".trigger").mouseenter(function () {
     var curAudio = $(this).find('audio');
     var allAudio = $('.sound');
    $.each(allAudio,function(ind,val){  
         $(this).get(0).pause();
         $(this).get(0).currentTime = 0;   
    });
     curAudio.get(0).play();
});
```

demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L9MnF/)

Comment: thank you a ton, but unfortunately it's not working :/ 
still the same as above: same sound is triggered by every div with the class ".trigger".

Comment: i edited my code above to make it more comprehendible. the sounds in my trigger -> <audio>-tags are different.

Comment: so you have different audio files right in each trigger class, right?

Answer (score 0):

OK, your first problem is that you have the same id ("sound") within every div, and ids have to be unique. I'd change that into a class (`class="sound"`)
Then, something like

```
$('.trigger').mouseenter(function() {
    $(".sound").get(0).pause();
    $(this).find(".sound").get(0).play();
});
```

I have not tested this code though.