# execute code depending on state of button

Tags: jquery, css, button, audio, toggle

i'm a terrible novice when it comes to jquery and i'm trying to build a menu (consisting of multiple divs with the same class) that plays a unique sound on hover. this part works thanks to [**some help from here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047638/unique-sound-when-hovering-multiple-instance-div).

now i'd additionally like to add a switch (not checkbox) somewhere on that page that disables this function depending on its state (like a on-off-switch)

here's how i do the sound-part:

```
<div class="trigger">
    <audio class="sound" preload="auto">
        <source src="sound1.mp3"></source>
        <source src="sound1.ogg"></source>
    </audio>
</div>

<div class="trigger">
    <audio class="sound" preload="auto">
         <source src="sound2.mp3"></source>
         <source src="sound2.ogg"></source>
    </audio>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$('.trigger').hover(
    function() {
        sound = $(this).children()[0];
        sound.play();
    }, function() {
        sound.pause();
        sound.currentTime = 0;
    }
);
```

as for the toggle-button part, i suppose i'd need something like this.. if so, i have no idea how to "mix" the two functions :)

```
$("#toggle_button").click(function(){
    if($("#OnOffDiv").hasClass("On"))
    {
        $("#OnOffDiv").removeClass("On");
        $("#OnOffDiv").addClass("Off");
        DO SOMETHING
);

    }
    else
    {
        $("#OnOffDiv").removeClass("Off");
        $("#OnOffDiv").addClass("On");
        $("#OnOffDiv").html("ON");
        DO SOMETHING ELSE
    }
});
```

i'd be gracious for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trim down that toggle part script by using `toggleClass()`:

```
$("#toggle_button").click(function () {
    $('#OnOffDiv').toggleClass('on off').text($('#OnOffDiv').attr('class'));
});
```

And then on your hover event, just check if `$('#OnOffDiv').hasClass('on')`:

```
$('.trigger').hover(function () {
    if ($('#OnOffDiv').hasClass('on')) {
        sound = $(this).children()[0];
        sound.play();
    }
}, function () {
    sound.pause();
    sound.currentTime = 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you just need a css rule set for when the button is on, since you should have a rule set for the button in its default state. So now you should have this:

```
$("#toggle_button").click(function(){
    $("toggle_button").toggleClass("on");
});
```

Alos, you really don't need a whole div just to store this information. Notice how that code changes the class of `toggle_button` and not of `OnOffDiv`.

Have you noticed something now? When `toggle_button` is toggled on, it has an `on` class. When it's toggled off, it doesn't. That means you can use `toggle_button` itself as a variable!

So now, if `$(#toggle_button).hasClass("on")` returns `true`, your hover code should work. When `hasClass("on")` returns `false`, it shouldn't do anything, or handle hovering in a different way.

Since you're a novice, I'll let you finalize the code on your own so that you can learn from it. I gave you everything you need to make it work. If you really can't solve it on your own, just post a comment and I'll give you the solution.